# Javascript Hide/Show div not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

im having trouble running javascript hide/show div using CSS classes, when i click on the trigger nothing happens. The relevant codes are the following:

HTML

```
        <a href="" onclick="toggleClass(test,hidden)">Click</a>
        <div id="test" class="hidden">
        test    
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 .hidden{
        display:none;
 }
```

JS

```
function toggleClass(eid, myclass) {
 var theEle = document.getElementById(eid);
 var eClass = theEle.className;

 if (eClass.indexOf(myclass) >= 0) {

 theEle.className = eClass.replace(myclass, "");
 } else{

   theEle.className  += "" +myclass;
}
}
```

Comment: any errors in your console?

Comment: oops, change onclick="toggleClass(test,hidden)"  to  onclick="toggleClass('test','hidden')"

Comment: i have tried running it on jsfiddle i get the following error {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: why not using Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not 100% certain, but im pretty sure you need to enclose the arguments in quotation marks

```
<a href="" onclick="toggleClass('test','hidden')">Click</a>
    <div id="test" class="hidden">
    test    
    </div>
```

Comment: You can be 100% sure of that!

Comment: nvm, this fixed it. i removed the href and it worked. thanks a lot

Comment: hmm when you do the `theEle.className  += "" +myclass;` do you intend to add another class to theEle? because you need to have space between classes and you add an empty string instead...

Answer (score 1):

two issues: you missed a "#" for the href + ' for the test and hidden (must be strings):

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleClass('test','hidden')">Click</a>
 <div id="test" class="hidden">
        test    
 </div>
```